# How to get the position of same elements in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I need your help to get the position of duplicate or same elements in an array.
For example

```
$arr =[6,5,3,7,40,45,7,6,3,32,86,40,5,3,7,40];
```

Result

```
6 = 0,7
5 =  1,11
3 =  2,8
7 = 3,6,14
40 = 4,11,15
45 =5 and so on.
```

Comment: SO volunteers are here to help you with the problems you have with your code, you seem to be asking a lot of questions with no code or even design effort. Please have a read of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach:

```
<?php
$arr =[6,5,3,7,40,45,7,6,3,32,86,40,5,3,7,40];

$pos = array();
foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
   $pos[$v][] = $k;   
}    

foreach($pos as $k => $v) {
   echo $k."=".implode(',', $v)."<br>";   
}    
?>
```

Result:

```
6=0,7
5=1,12
3=2,8,13
7=3,6,14
40=4,11,15
45=5
32=9
86=10
```